# Airflow connection list check through python operator

Tags: airflow

Before executing the DAG, I want to check whether a particular connection id is present in the connection list or not. I dont have any mechanismn of retaining a connection. Even if I create a connection through GUI, when server reboots all the connections gets removed.

Following is the task I thought I should add but thenI got an ascii error when I ran it, may be because the command return a table that might not be adequately parsed by the logger.

```
def create_connection(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs.get('ds'))

list_conn = BashOperator(
    task_id='list_connections',
    bash_command='airflow connections --l',
    xcom_push=True)

conns = list_conn.execute(context=kwargs)
logging.info(conns)

if not conns:
    new_conn = Connection(conn_id='xyz', conn_type='s3',
                          host='https://api.example.com')
    session = settings.Session()
    session.add(new_conn)
    session.commit()
    logging.info('Connection is created')
```

Question: Is there any way I would get to know in Airflow DAG itself that the connection is added or not. If its already there then I would not create a new connection.

Comment: Since you already have `Connection` imported, `session.query(Connection)` should list out all the connections

Comment: Thanks buddy that worked. If you want to post the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`session.query(Connection)` should do the trick.

```
def list_connections(**context):
    session = settings.Session()
    return session.query(Connection)

list_conn = PythonOperator(
    task_id='list_connections',
    python_callable=list_connections,
    provide_context=True,
)
```

Please make sure all the code is contained within tasks. Or to phrase it correctly, they should execute during `run time` instead of `load time`. Adding the code directly in DAG file cause it to run during load time which is not recommended.

Comment: session.query(Connection).all() if you need the list of conn_id

Comment: Hello. I just tried this and **session.query(Connection)** is returning the just query. Do I need to run any execute method?

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answers work perfectly. I had a scenario where I needed to get a connection by connection id to create the DAG. So I had to get it outside the task and in the DAG creation itself.
The following code worked for me:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

conn = BaseHook.get_connection(connection)
```

Hope this might help someone! :)

Comment: In Airflow 2+ it's now: from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook